# Delphi VCL В каком модуле находится TImageCollection_ComEditor попап меню IDE

Tags: delphi, vcl

Мне хотелось бы унаследоватся от редактора попап меню `TImageCollection` но я не могу его найти. Или как самостоятельно вызвать редактор коллекции картинок в режиме разработки?

```
uses DesignEditors;

    TImageCollection_ComEditor=class(TDefaultEditor ??)
      public
        function GetVerbCount:integer; override;
        function GetVerb(Index:integer):string; override;
        procedure ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); override;
        procedure Edit; override;
    end;
```

[image: ico]

получилось узнать имя класса но сам модуль не могу найти где этот класс

```
procedure TAmImageCollection_ComEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
var P: TAmImageCollection;
    N: TImageCollection;
    C:IComponentEditor;
  s:string;
  I:Integer;
begin
  inherited;

    case Index of
         0:begin
             P:= TAmImageCollection(self.Component);

             N:= TImageCollection.Create(P);
           //  N.Assign(P);
             C:= GetComponentEditor(N,Designer);
             s:= (C as TComponentEditor).UnitName+' '+(C as TComponentEditor).ClassName ;
            
            // TImageCollectionEditor
             InputQuery('','',s); //>>  s = WinXReg TImageCollectionEditor
             
             //а запустить можно так 
            // есть ли вариант по лучше 
             N:= TImageCollection.Create(P);
             try
               N.Assign(P);
               try
               C:= GetComponentEditor(N,Designer);
               C.ExecuteVerb(0);
               finally
                 P.Assign(N);
               end;
             finally
               N.Free;
             end;

             exit;
....
```

Comment: [Документация](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/DesignEditors) молчит как партизан?

Comment: @ 
Владимир Клыков 
 а можете подсказать по этому похожему вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1446197/delphi-vcl-design-time-ide-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-tpropertyeditor-%d1%81-tdefaulteditor

Comment: Нет, никогда не страдал баловством в визуальными компонентами в десигнтайм.