# delphi vcl design time Ide как показать TPropertyEditor с TDefaultEditor

Tags: delphi, ide, vcl

как показать редактор property в IDE когда кликаешь на попап меню в редакторе

кликаю на элемент TDefaultEditor в редакторе компонента и нужно найти TPropertyEditor по имени property и запустить как бы было если кликнул на редакторе property и запустить его
на скринах желаемый результат

1.Кликаю

[image: Кликаю]

2. ишу property с именем Items
3. запускаю

Хотелось бы узнать как найти проперти редактор и запустить его
И это нужно сделать не зная класса проперти а пользуясь только тем что дает
редактор компонента.

Зачем почему??
так как я не могу найти тот класс редактора от которого можно унаследоватся

в компоненте TImageCollection

удается только переназначить свойства а не добавить новые

похожий вопрос задавал ранее по поводу [редактора TImageCollection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1446108/delphi-vcl-%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-timagecollection-comeditor-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-ide?noredirect=1#comment2581953_1446108)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решил так

```
function AmImageCollectionShowEditor(Component:TAmImageCollection;Designer: IDesigner):IProperty;
function AmImageCollectionGetPropertyImages(Component:TAmImageCollection;Designer: IDesigner):IProperty;

implementation

 type
 TLocGetPropImages = class
   private
    PropImage:IProperty;
    Component:TAmImageCollection;
    Designer: IDesigner;
    procedure Proc(const Prop: IProperty);
    function Get: IProperty;
 end;

{ TLocShowEditor }

function TLocGetPropImages.Get: IProperty;
var ComsList: IDesignerSelections;
begin
  ComsList := TDesignerSelections.Create;
  ComsList.Add(Component);
  GetComponentProperties(ComsList, tkProperties, Designer, Proc);
  Result:= PropImage;
end;
procedure TLocGetPropImages.Proc(const Prop: IProperty);
begin
   if Prop.GetName = 'Images' then
     PropImage:= Prop;
end;

function AmImageCollectionShowEditor(Component:TAmImageCollection;Designer: IDesigner):IProperty;
begin
     Result:= AmImageCollectionGetPropertyImages(Component,Designer);
     if Assigned(Result) then
     Result.Edit; //показ окна редактора (т.е запуск формы к которой не знаю как получить доступ как бы кликая в редакторе проперти)
end;
function AmImageCollectionGetPropertyImages(Component:TAmImageCollection;Designer: IDesigner):IProperty;
var P:TLocGetPropImages;
begin
    P:=TLocGetPropImages.Create;
    try
       P.PropImage:=nil;
       P.Component:= Component;
       P.Designer:=  Designer;
       Result:= P.Get;
    finally
      P.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Запуск так

```
procedure TAmImageCollection_ComEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
var P: TAmImageCollection;
begin
  inherited;
    P:= Component as TAmImageCollection;
    case Index of
         0:  AmImageCollectionShowEditor(P,Designer);
```